# How to create inheritance in linq to sql class with abstract class

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, inheritance

I want to have an abstract class with 3 classes extending it which i need to save to a database using linq. I've made a table with all the attributes of the parent class and the 3 subclasses.

Can't figure out how to properly set this up in the OR designer.

When i set TimeRecord's Inheritance modifier to "abstract" i get the following error:
[error](http://peecee.dk/uploads/052011/error.png)

[OR Design](http://peecee.dk/uploads/052011/ordesign.PNG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GetTable() method tries to create an instance of your class which is abstract it can't do that 
remove abstarct modifier from your class